# Looking for free and reliable host for images

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting, free, image-hosting

For [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/34937/sharing-banner-on-3rd-party-websites-concerned-about-limited-resources), (as the question, that the link links to, has been removed, "*this*" refers to *sharing a banner on 3rd party websites concerned about limited resources*) I'm looking for a free and reliable host for images, where I can share the image with a direct link. Google Picasa is not a good option because it produces a very long direct link, any other suggestions?

Comment: This is a [shopping question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Comment: ^^ indeed.... Dunno more people using stack these days than Google ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just trying to share a banner image? and have it hosted/served from somewhere?  You can use windows skydrive, google drive, or dropbox.

You can also put it up on a cheap godaddy instance or amazon aws and setup cname in dns settings so you can have an easy url to point to the image file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. yes, I need it only for sharing a banner, but I also don't want to use Picasa, Google Drive or SkyDrive, although I know they're all very reliable, but the file's direct link is very long... I think that makes it hard for users to copy and paste the code... I don't want to pay anything too...

Comment: What do you think about services like imageshack.us? are they reliable?

Comment: Well, since you said it is copy and paste the code, why you care about the length?

Comment: I think it would be easier for others to use shorter and simpler codes, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to share images with people via a download link, Dropbox.com would work for you. You'll be limited to 2 Gigs free, but if you just have projects to share from time to time, dropbox lets you send people a link where they can view/download the pictures.